# ORACLE: Range between Weeks

Tags: oracle11g, between, date-range, dayofweek, connect-by

How would one create my expected results. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Master Calendar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  --CA.CALENDAR_DATE,
          TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CALENDAR_DATE                                
               TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 7, 'MM/DD/YY-') || 
          TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(CALENDAR_DATE, 'Monday') - 1, 'MM/DD/YY') AS WEEK_OF_YEAR,

          ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY CALENDAR_DATE) AS MasterCalendar_RNK

         FROM CALENDAR CA
         WHERE 1=1  
           --AND CA.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -12) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
           --AND CA.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) -5 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)
           ORDER BY TO_DATE(CALENDAR_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC
```

Input:

```
Member    StartDate    EndDate    
 A          1/31/17      
 B          2/1/17      2/15/17
```

Expected Results:

```
Member    StartDate    EndDate    Week_Of_Year        Active
  A         1/31/17                  1/30/17-2/5/17      1
  A         1/31/17                  2/6/17-2/12/17      1
  A         1/31/17                  2/13/17-2/19/17     1
  B         2/1/17      2/15/17      1/30/17/2/5/17      1
  B         2/1/17      2/15/17      2/6/17-2/12/17      1
  B         2/1/17      2/15/17      2/13/17-2/19/17     1
```

Comment: Any thoughts? Do I need to clarify anything?

Comment: I have edited my question above.